# Change the number of Approvals required for existing rule Gitlab API

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I'm using the [Merge request approavls](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_request_approvals.html) Gitlab API to create approval rules for merge requests.

I want to control the number `approvals requiered` for an exisitng approval rule using merge request approvals API `POST /projects/:id/approval_rules`

I dont want to use `PUT /projects/:id/approval_rules/:approval_rule_id` API as I dont know the approval rule id but I have it's name.

Is there a way to achive that without additional API call to get approvals list, find the name and fetch the ID out of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The endpoint to update a rule requires the rule's ID. If you only have the name of the rule, but not its ID, you will need to first [get the list of approval rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_request_approvals.html#get-project-level-rules) and match the name to the ID first.

There is no capability to modify a rule in the API without the ID.